# Segue from UINavigationController back to Root Controller?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Currently I have a Navigation Controller in a separate storyboard that utilities an exit button. This exit button SHOULD go back to the rootViewController(thats in mainstoryboard) Which is an iSplitViewController...

I can't figure out the correct Segue commands to make this work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Link the button to an IBAction method that calls:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```